# bcp out or select query with output in a file, which is faster?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, bcp

I need to unload around 5-6 million rows into a file from a sybase ASE database table. What is the best way to do that: bcping out or select * from... and storing the output to the file? 
The table has some indexes on it. The database server is on a different machine than the file needs to be created. 
Any ideas how can it be made faster?

Comment: Just to clarify there is no condition, I need to unload all rows of the table.

Answer (score 2):

The BCP utility is designed for that purpose.  It should be faster than any select *, particularly if you use the native mode, and not the character mode.